# What is the best algorithm for removing every kth character in a string of length N?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, assembly

I know there is a naive algorithm that is order N and I'm about convinced that's the only one to use. Is there any other that is:

1. Asymptotically better
2. Pipelineable i.e. RAW,WAR friendly
3. Multithreadable.

I'm sure there is one for (1) but I'm not so sure about (2) and (3). If you also want to mention why this is a good interview question. I'd love to know that as well.

Comment: if you use a binary search tree for storing individual characters, where the sorting/order of the nodes is based on the index of characters, then you can go down to `O(log k)` asymptotically. But the constant factors will be much, **much** worse (due to pointer traversals and the general cache unfriendliness of trees).

Comment: *"If you also want to mention why this is a good interview question. I'd love to know that as well."* --> Because the best interview questions do not have a definitive answer, but, as you have, draw you out to explore alternatives.

Comment: What is to be returned? Is the question asking for the return of the kth character, or the string with the kth character removed?

Comment: The string with the kth character removed. Bonus points for doing it inplace. Also Para feel free to post that as an answer, answers that only do 1 or 1 and 2 are fine as well as ones that do 1,2 and 3

Comment: Is the string to be represented as an array of characters ? I think the interviewer may have wanted to be asked that sort of question to start out a discussion on other ways of representing strings / sets of strings.

Comment: Am I thinking about it wrong? Seems if you start at `i=k` and say `s[i]=s[i+1]` until you get to `i==N`, the order would be O(N-k), right? With a max of N-1.

Comment: Yea its a standard C array.

Comment: No you have to remove every kth character in the case of 3 its 3,6,9 etc. but now it makes sense. what you do is s[i]=s[i+i/3] and its still order N but in place.

Comment: @West then you better change the title

Comment: Oooooh, you didn't say *every* kth character, but just the kth character. You should probably edit and clarify.

Comment: @West, yes, what you mentioned will work, but it has RAW dependencies and is not multithreadable. Is multithreadable a requirement?

Comment: No, just a curiosity of mine.

Comment: @West well, the "every k-th character" problem isn't quite the same. Even if you use a BST, it will take `O(N/k * log(k))` time, which is again just `O(n)` if `k` is constant.

Comment: Thanks guys, this makes me feel dumb but knowing where I went wrong is good.

Comment: A relatively simple way to look at the asymptotic complexity question is that no matter the details of how you go about the removal, all but `k - 1` characters have to be moved to new positions.  That's `o(N - (k - 1))` = `o(N)` (small `o`), so the upper bound cannot be any better than that.  Since you can indeed do the job in `O(N)` operations, that's your best possible upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious method is easy to do in-place

```
void remove_every_kth(char *s, size_t len, int k)
{
    // UNTESTED CODE, there might be an off-by-one or a wrong loop boundary
    if (k < len)
        return;

    const char *endp = s + len;
    size_t offset = 1;
    // we skip the s[i] = s[i] memmove at offset=0.
    for (s+=k-1 ; s + offset < endp-(k-1) ; s+=k-1) {
        // every iteration copies k-1 characters, and advances s by k-1
        memmove(s, s+offset, k-1);
        offset++;
    }
    size_t lastchunk = endp - (s+offset);  // some number (less than k) of bytes left in the input
    memmove(s, s+offset, lastchunk);
    s[lastchunk] = '\0';
}
// equivalently, we could have kept a pointer to the read position,
// like const char* read = s+offset;
// and incremented it by k, while incrementing s by k-1


    // for (int i=0 ; i < k ; i++)  // implicit length string
    //    if (!s[i]) return;    // check for length < k
```

Since `k` is constant, you can calculate where to find the input character for any output position.  `out[i] = in[i + i/k]`.  There's nothing data-dependent, so this is certainly multithreadable if you don't need to do it in-place, and you have the length of the string in advance.  Just farm out the necessary `memcpy` calls to multiple threads.  (I wrote the simple version with `memmove` instead of a char-pointer loop to make this more obvious, as well as for much better performance with medium to large `k`.  It probably sucks for small `k`.)

For multithreaded in-place, there's something to gain if `k` is large, so that even towards the end of a long string, the source and destination of most of the copying is within the same chunk.  Each work unit does:

- don't touch the first `offset = chunk_number * chunk_size / k` bytes, the previous work unit needs to read them.
- save the second `offset` bytes to a temp array.
- `memmove(chunk + offset, chunk + offset*2, chunk_size - offset)` (i.e. do the memmove for all the bytes that aren't needed by the previous work unit).
- spin-wait for the *previous* chunk to be marked as done by the thread handling it.  (Prob. with a separate data structure, because just watching the data at the last overlapping position won't work.  It might be overwritten with the same value.)
- copy from the temp buffer to the beginning of the chunk, where the data belongs
- mark the work chunk as completed.

For small `k`, in-place multithread is futile, because most of the bytes in a chunk need to be overwritten with bytes from later chunks.  (very large chunks help some.)